# If $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is random, and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is fixed, what is $Var(Y - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY)$?

Tags: variance

If $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is random, and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is fixed, what is $Var(Y - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY)$?

\begin{align*}
Var(Y - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY) &= Var(Y) + X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TVar(Y)X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T - 2Cov(Y, X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY)\\
&= Var(Y) + X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TVar(Y)X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T - 2X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TCov(Y, Y)X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\\
&= Var(Y) - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TVar(Y)X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\\
\end{align*}

Is the above correct?

Comment: What is the context? i.e., Var(Z), What does Z  represent?

Comment: I just wanted to double check my variance calculation in this context where $Y$ is a random vector.

Comment: The thing being subtracted inside the VAR statement  is $X \hat{\beta}$ so it's the variance of the $\hat{\epsilon}$ so it's the variance of the $n \times 1$ vector of residual estimates. Check it out in a regression text to make sure but, if the $\epsilon$ are all assumed to have the same variance then, IIRC, the best estimate is the SSE/(n- number of coefficients )).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot simplify the variance as you have done.  Perhaps the simplest method is to note that one can we-rewrite
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y - X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}Y = \left[I_n - X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\right]Y.
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Var} \left(Y - X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}Y\right) &=& \mbox{Var} \left(\left[I_n - X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\right]Y\right) \\ &=&
\left[I_n - X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\right] \mbox{Var} \left(Y\right) \left[I_n - X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: So what you're saying is that the first line of my work is incorrect? In the 1-dimensional case, i.e., if $Z, W \in \mathbb{R}$ are random variables, and $a$ is a constant, then $Var(Z-aW) = Var(Z) + a^2Var(W) - 2aCov(Z, W)$. However, in my original question we're dealing with variance of difference in two random vectors, then the variance of a difference between two random vectors is not equal to the variance of each random vector plus twice the covariance?

Comment: Exactly because it is not the case in general that $X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime} \mbox{Var} (Y)$ is equal to $\mbox{Var} (Y)X\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}$.

Comment: You need to start with first principles: the variance of a vector is defined as $\mbox{Var}(Y) = \mbox{Cov}(Y,Y) = \mbox{E}(YY^{\prime}) - \mbox{E}\left(Y\right) \mbox{E}\left(Y^{\prime}\right)$.  And one can show that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, that $\mbox{Var}(X+Y) = \mbox{Var}(X) + \mbox{Var}(Y) + \mbox{Cov}(X,Y) + \mbox{Cov}(Y,X)$.  And $ \mbox{Cov}(X,Y) \ne \mbox{Cov}(Y,X)$ in general since $\mbox{Cov}(X,Y)=\mbox{E}(XY^{\prime}) - \mbox{E}\left(X\right) \mbox{E}\left(Y^{\prime}\right)$.